# Can't get Zend pdf show in browser

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf, zend-pdf

I've got a strange problem with zend pdf, I just can't get the pdf to show 
in my action i've got this code:

```
$this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();

$pdf = new Zend_Pdf('path/to/file.pdf');

$this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-pdf', true);
$this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-disposition', 'inline; filename=filetrace.pdf', true);
$this->getResponse()->setBody($pdf->render());
```

Zend creates this stacktrace:

```
#0 E:\SRVApps\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Pdf.php(303): Zend_Pdf_Parser->__construct('http://example...', Object(Zend_Pdf_ElementFactory_Proxy), false)
#1 E:\wwwroot\test\htdocs\application\modules\dashboard\controllers\FileController.php(171): Zend_Pdf->__construct('http://example...')
#2 E:\SRVApps\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Controller\Action.php(513): Dashboard_FileController->showAction()
#3 E:\SRVApps\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php(289): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('showAction')
#4 E:\SRVApps\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#5 E:\SRVApps\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#6 E:\SRVApps\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#7 E:\wwwroot\test\htdocs\public\index.php(26): Zend_Application->run()
#8 {main}
```

When creating an new pdf there is no problem

Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: What shows up instead of the PDF?

Comment: Application error / Internal Server Error

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old question but I found the answer to this through trial and error.  This is what my action looks like to get just the pdf to show up in the browser.  This works in Chrome.  I haven't tested it in any other browser.

```
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    $this->getResponse()
        ->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename=foo.pdf')
        ->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
    $pdf = Zend_Pdf::load('/path/to/my.pdf');
    echo $pdf->render();
```

Answer (score 1):

Method 1: Get the binary string outside of Zend_Pdf

```
$file = file_get_contents('path/to/file.pdf')
$pdf = new Zend_Pdf($file);
```

Method 2: Set the `$load` parameter `true`

```
$pdf = new Zend_Pdf('path/to/file.pdf', null, true);
```

Method 3: Use the static `load`-method

```
$pdf = Zend_Pdf::load('path/to/file.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 1.9, which uses `Zend_Pdf`, to render PDF in browser, the following works for me:

```php
// In controller action
$filename = 'foo.pdf';
$pdf = Zend_Pdf::load('path/to/foo.pdf');
$content = $pdf->render();
$contentLength = strlen($content);

$this->getResponse()
    ->setHttpResponseCode(200)
    ->setHeader('Pragma', 'public', true)
    ->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', true)
    ->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf', true)
    ->setHeader('Content-Length', $contentLength, true)
    ->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename="'.$filename.'"', true)
    ->setHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary', true)
    ->setHeader('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes', true)
    ->setBody($content);
// Exit controller action
```